# Nginx duplicate listen options for [::]:80 error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

When I run the command to test my configuration I get an error saying there are multiple duplicates for `[::]:80`. Before that I had an issue with duplicate multiple default servers.

When I had the issue with multiple default servers, my file looked like this

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name munki;

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

location /report {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

location /munki_repo/ {
    alias /usr/local/munki_repo/;
    autoindex off;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

To resolve that problem, I changed the configuration to:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name munki;

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

location /report {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

location /munki_repo/ {
    alias /usr/local/munki_repo/;
    autoindex off;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

After the change I started getting a "duplicate options for [::]:80" error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this. This is my first time working with Nginx. Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Please post the error message (`nginx -t` output). What nginx version are you running? `ipv6only=on` might not be needed anymore. I have this in my server block: `listen 80;listen [::]:80;` and it runs fine. Do you have any other server blocks?

Comment: That worked what you suggested Thanks! Never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'm creating an answer out of my earlier comment.

Please post the error message (`nginx -t` output) as it could contain some useful insight.

What nginx version are you running? Option `ipv6only=on` might not be needed anymore and on the contrary potentially create issues. I have this in my server block and it runs fine:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
```

Do you have any other server blocks you didn't post that might possibly conflict with eachother?

---

**Explanation:** let's read the current (1.13) nginx [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen):

> `ipv6only=on|off`
>   this parameter (0.7.42) determines (via the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option) whether an IPv6 socket listening on a wildcard address `[::]`
>   will accept only IPv6 connections or both IPv6 and IPv4 connections.
>   This parameter is turned on by default. It can only be set once on
>   start.

***This parameter is turned on by default*** means that you should not use `ipv6only=on`. It does not do any good and can potentially create problems (see next point).

***It can only be set once*** means that if you have it more than once *anywhere* in your configuration (such as in different server blocks), it will throw an error: `nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:80`.