# How to manage multiple sites on the same server with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, domain, https, subdomain

I have 2 sites on the same Nginx server.

My first site https://www.example.com all the following addresses must redirect to this domain:

xx.xx.xx.xxx

http://example.com

http://www.example.com

https://example.com

My second site https://analytics.example.com the following address must redirect to this domain:

http://analytics.example.com

If I disable the second site, the first site works fine.

There is a conflict when I activate multiple sites with Nginx. How can I fix that ?

With the settings below :

```
ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www-example-com:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

www.example.com

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/www-example-com/web;
    index index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

    brotli on;
    brotli_comp_level 6;
    brotli_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

    expires 1209600s;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        expires off;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

analytics.example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name analytics.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://analytics.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
    server_name analytics.example.com;
    root /var/www/analytics-example-com/web;
    index report.html;

    auth_basic "Protected";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/analytics-example-com/web/.htpasswd;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/analytics.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/analytics.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

For both sites, I have the same error :

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx duplicate listen options for \[::\]:80 error](https://serverfault.com/questions/842492/nginx-duplicate-listen-options-for-80-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ipv6only=on` is redundant as this is the default. It does not need to appear in any `listen` directives anywhere in your configuration.

If present, it also can appear only once for any given address and port pair.

You should remove it from all `listen` directives.

Comment: Ok so I completely remove `ipv6only=on` from both files ?

Comment: @ML19 Remove it everywhere it appears.

Comment: Awesome it works

Answer (score 1):

The error message `nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for...` means that you have applied a parameter more than once for the same port. That is, the second `ipv6only=on` parameter in your code here:

example.com:

```
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
```

analytics.example.com

```
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on; # <- this is duplicate and raises the error
```

The clue is hidden away in the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen):

> The listen directive can have several additional parameters specific to socket-related system calls. These parameters can be specified in any listen directive, but only once for a given address:port pair.

This applies for any 'additional' parameters (like `deferred`, `reuseport`, `so_keepalive`, etc). Of course, as mentioned already, you no longer need to specify `ipv6only=on` at all.

The best practice then, would be to **specify any parameters on your first or default_server declaration only**. It can be assumed subsequent `listen` directives will inherit these.