# How do I point my Subdomain to correct root folder

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps, subdomain

I have my production site set up and now I'm trying to setup a dev/staging site to run live tests in.

I'm having issues pointing my subdomain to the correct root path on my Laravel app.

**I need the following:**

- dev.example.com to point to `root /var/www/dev/public;`
- example.com and www.example.com to point to root /var/www/laravel/public;
- currently everything is going to `/var/www/laravel/public`

**Server:**

- Ubuntu 18.10 x64
- Nginx

I have a domain `example.com` and I made a subdomain called `dev.example.com`
each reference to the domain is in my SSL Cert via certbot/LetsEncrypt. www.example.com, example.com and dev.example.com

**DNS for Subdomain:**

`A (Record) | dev (Name) | 140.xx.xx.xx (Data)`

I have 2 folders located here:

- /var/www/`laravel`/public (My Main Production site)
- /var/www/`dev`/public (My Development Site)

In sites-available `/etc/nginx/sites-available` I have the `default` file with the following configurations.

(I've tried multiple variation of this, but this is where I left off)

```
 server {

    root /var/www/laravel/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com dev.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com

server {

    if ($host = dev.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name dev.example.com;
    root /var/www/dev/public;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

server {

    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

server {

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Again...

- I need `dev.example.com` to point to `root /var/www/dev/public;`
- I need `example.com and www.example.com` to point to `root /var/www/laravel/public;`

Any help in figuring this out would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `server` block to serve the new hostname with the `root` that you desire. You can either copy the rest of the configuration from the existing block, or later, make use of `include`s to DRY it up.

Comment: I've tried that by duplicating my default block and editing it for the `dev site` , but I get the error `nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: @cwd That's an unrelated issue; the answer is [here](https://serverfault.com/a/956942/126632). Fix that, then duplicate the `server` block.